# Python 2.x and 3.x RC4 encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to implement RC4 encryption in Python 2.x and 3.x, but the following code outputs different encrypted strings based on the version of Python running.

```
def crypt(key, data):
    S = list(range(256))
    j = 0

    for i in list(range(256)):
        j = (j + S[i] + ord(key[i % len(key)])) % 256
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]

    j = 0
    y = 0
    out = []

    for char in data:
       j = (j + 1) % 256
       y = (y + S[j]) % 256
       S[j], S[y] = S[y], S[j]
       out.append(chr(ord(char) ^ S[(S[j] + S[y]) % 256]))

    return ''.join(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = '123456'                  # proof of concept
    plain = 'this is test data'     # proof of concept

    encrypted = crypt(key, plain)
    print('Encrypted: \n' + encrypted)
```

Running with Python 2.x outputs:

`Encrypted: 
t?Zf?
     RQ??Z ??`

Running with Python 3.x outputs:

`Encrypted: 
tZf¼
     RQÂÙZ º`

I first thought this was an issue with encoding and played around with that (ASCII and UTF-8), but no dice. Anyone have any ideas why this is outputting different data with the same key and plaintext? The goal is to have a string that I can pass around. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In Python 3, both your `key` and `plain` are Unicode strings and everything else goes downhill from there. If you use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` you'll get the same problem with Python 2. Try with `key = b'123456'`, as well as `plain = b'this is test data'` and drop the `ord()` calls.

Comment: Tried both of those, but that did not seem to work. Gives the "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" error.

Comment: Ah, I forgot. That `chr()` also needs to go. You are dealing with raw bytes

Comment: I removed the chr() and ord() calls per your suggestion, but still no luck. Here's a gist showing the changes: https://gist.github.com/t3ntman/ca414ba11fa8bbe80138cb408059d16b

Comment: Update: Ended up using unichr() with .encode('utf-8') and the encrypted string is the same in both 2.x and 3.x (yay progress), but decryption does not work as expected. it just stays the same. gist for updated code: https://gist.github.com/t3ntman/238663f8108c548941f2b01f4907c480

Comment: Solved: https://gist.github.com/t3ntman/201e439bc7818a25af236cac6b3eacc6

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution. Posted the function here: https://gist.github.com/t3ntman/201e439bc7818a25af236cac6b3eacc6